# Expand/Collapse table rows with nested rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to create a table with the following structure: 
Row1          datacolumn1 datacolumn2 datacolumn2
 SubRow1      datacolumn1 datacolumn2 datacolumn2
  SubRow2     datacolumn1 datacolumn2 datacolumn2
   SubRow3    datacolumn1 datacolumn2 datacolumn2

I want to the subrows to expand/collapse on click. I just cant seem to make it work with tables. I know lists would be a better option but tables are much easier to maintain.

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="row1 head1">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row1 head2 closed">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row1 head3">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row1 head4">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row1 head5">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row2 head1">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>

    <tr class="row2 head4">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="row2 head5">
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cash and Equivalents</td>
        <td>000,000</td>
        <td>000,000</td>

    </tr>

</tbody>
```

on row click, i call the following function:

```
holdingsTree: function(that){
    var stack = '',
        classes = ba.splitClasses(that.attr('class')),
        nextRow = ba.getClassNumber(classes[1], "head");

    if (that.next().hasClass('head'+nextRow)){
        if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0]) && that.next().hasClass('open')){
            that.nextUntil('.head1').hide().addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        } else if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0])){
            stack = that.nextUntil('.head1');
            $.each(stack, function(i, item){ if ($(item).hasClass('head' + (nextRow))){ $(this).show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed'); } });
        }
    } else if (that.next().hasClass('head'+ (nextRow+1))){
        if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0]) && that.next().hasClass('open')){
            that.nextUntil('.head1').hide().addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        } else if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0])){
            stack = that.nextUntil('.head1');
            $.each(stack, function(i, item){ if ($(item).hasClass('head' + (nextRow+1))){ $(this).show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed'); } });
        }
    } else if (that.next().hasClass('head'+ (nextRow+2))){
        if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0]) && that.next().hasClass('open')){
            that.nextUntil('.head1').hide().addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
            return;
        } else if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0])){
            stack = that.nextUntil('.head'+ (nextRow+3));
            $.each(stack, function(i, item){ if ($(item).hasClass('head' + (nextRow+2))){ $(this).show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed'); } });
            //stack.find('.head'+(nextRow+2)).show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
        }
    } else if (that.next().hasClass('head'+ (nextRow+3))){
        if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0]) && that.next().hasClass('open')){
            that.nextUntil('.head1').hide().addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        } else if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0])){
            stack = that.nextUntil('.head1');
            $.each(stack, function(i, item){ if ($(item).hasClass('head' + (nextRow+3))){ $(this).show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed'); } });
        }
    } else if (that.next().hasClass('head'+ (nextRow+4))){
        if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0]) && that.next().hasClass('open')){
            that.nextUntil('.head1').hide().addClass('closed').removeClass('open');
        } else if (that.next().hasClass(classes[0])){
            that.nextUntil('.head1').show().addClass('open').removeClass('closed');
        }
    } 

},

splitClasses: function(names){
    var names = names.split(' ');
    return names;
},

getClassNumber: function(name, pretext){
    var result = name.split(pretext);
    console.log(parseInt(result[1]) + 1);
    return parseInt(result[1]) + 1;
}
```

ITs very bad. I know. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can have a class for the rows you call parents, and a class for the rows you call children, and toggle their display.

Here's how:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [];
        while($row.next().hasClass('child')) {
             children.push($row.next());
             $row = $row.next();
        }            
        return children;
    }        

    $('.parent').on('click', function() {

        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function() {
            $(this).toggle();
        })
    });

})
```

Check this fiddle for the complete running code http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/3/
And please accept the answer if this solves your problem!

Good luck!

EDIT: to work on more levels one way is to have a level attribute. So here is the updated version which should work on any number of levels. http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [], level = $row.attr('data-level');
        while($row.next().attr('data-level') > level) {
             children.push($row.next());
             $row = $row.next();
        }            
        return children;
    }        

    $('.parent').on('click', function() {

        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function() {
            $(this).toggle();
        })
    });

})
```

Comment: Instead of toggle, you can use fadeToggle(), or slideToggle() for a different effect.

Comment: takes care of only a single level of nesting. i have multiple nesting levels to take care of..

Comment: thanks for the help. but it still has bugs. once u collapse all the children rows and then try to collapse the top most parent, it only collapses the next() child.

Comment: Check this one: http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/13/  These are drafts, it just points you in the right direction, you should experiment with it and improve solution.

Comment: @Angel changed  line 16 of http://jsfiddle.net/T8t2r/9/ to `$(this).slideToggle(500);` seems not working?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to make out what you are trying to do from that example.

What you are trying to do should be fairly simple - what I'd do is rewrite from scratch, using the following concepts:

1. Give each clickable item (row) it's own ID, but have them all in one 'clickable' class
2. Give each sub row a class based off of the ID of the clickable parent - such as '[id]-sub'
3. Set up a click event on the 'clickable' class, where you determine the clicked Item ID, and use that to toggle (hide/show) all rows with class '[clicked ID]-sub'

Doing it that way, you should have much less code, and it should be much more readable.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Ah, DKSan suggests DataTables - I've actually used the DataTables Details Rows for this sort of thing too, but unless you need the rest of DataTables for other purposes, I'd personally recommend avoiding it - it can be a lot of pain getting the details row working exactly how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$('.mySelectorOfNOTSubRow').toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('.mySelectorOfNOTSubRow').show();
    }, function(){
        $(this).nextUntil('.mySelectorOfNOTSubRow').hide();
});
```

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr class="head"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="head"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="head"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
     <tr class="sub"><td></td></tr>
...
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.sub{display: none;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cGhE7/)

Comment: this only takes care of a single level of nesting. I have to take care of upto 5 levels of nesting.

Answer (score -1):

As you are already using jQuery, you could go with the plugin [datatales](http://datatables.net/).

As you can see in the example section of the page, theres exactly what you are trying to achieve with your code.