# R DT expand/collapse nested rows by assigning 'child' and 'parent' classes to rows

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to implement collapsible child rows in a R data table by assigning a "child" class to the rows that I want to be child rows and a "parent" class to the rows that I want to be parent rows. Is it possible to have child rows in an R data table that are actual rows in your data table? I found an example for defining child rows for each row based on data in the row for R data tables: http://rstudio.github.io/DT/002-rowdetails.html. However, I am hoping to only display 'total' rows from my data and make all non-total rows child rows. The child rows will have the same columns and format as the parent rows.

I found a solution for JS, but I am having a difficult time getting it to work using callback.

Here is the JS solution: 
[Expand/Collapse table rows with nested rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574586/expand-collapse-table-rows-with-nested-rows)

Here is my attempt with a basic example in R:

```
library(DT)
datatable(
  cbind(' ' = '&oplus;', mtcars), escape = -2,
  options = list(
   rowCallback=DT::JS('function(row,data,index){
       if(index%2==1) {$("td",row).addClass("child")};
       if(index%2==0) {$("td",row).addClass("parent")};
    }'),
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0, 2, 3)),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
    )
  ),

  callback = JS("

    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [];
        while($row.next().hasClass('child')) {
             children.push($row.next());
             $row = $row.next();
        }            
        return children;
    }        

    $('.parent').on('click', function() {

        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function() {
            $(this).toggle();
        })
    });"



))
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could You find any solution? I have the same task :)